# Flash Video Problem Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video, flash

I have looked in multiple other questions and none of them seem to have the right answer for me. I have tried Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox to get Flash working and none of them work. I have manually installed and used the one from the Software Center and neither work. I am at a loss here, I can't watch any videos online. The videos plays but then stutters and lags. Sometimes it will also go at a 3x speed.

Im running a Lenovo T400 with a Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) Graphics Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem with your audio. Try toggling with your audio options. You can find your options by clicking the sound icon at the top near where you see power button:

[image: top bar]

Then click on `Sound Settings`. In there, toggle  between the pictures of cards just below `Play sound through`. This should solve your problem

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yeah, I have Restricted Extras and it hasnt worked. I also tried to get Flash Aid but it got taken down off the Firefox App Market.

Comment: Chromium should have worked, as it uses a plugin similar to flash

Comment: Exactly, it should have worked, but it doesnt. Which is why im drawing a total blank. If it helps, the videos play but they studder and lag.

Comment: Right. And no I didnt, I still have a few left. Ill try that.

Comment: Okay, I did the updates and now instead of slow and laggy it goes at like...3x speed.

Comment: No, though it changed from slow to extremely fast.

Comment: Yup, exactly like that.

Comment: EDIT: For some reason now it deicded to work! I guess toggling with my audio options did help! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You can disable ads for firefox(by going to the add ons and installing adblockerpro)  and chromium (by going to chrome web store and searching the same thing)