# Choppy and/or extremely fast video playback

Tags: sound, video

Tried Ubuntu, and now Mint, had the same issue on both and asked questions on both and didn't get an answer. I thought it might be a flash problem, but I'm not convinced of that. When I play a video, it often is choppy or "skips" for a couple of frames. Sometimes the audio and video are then not lined up. Sometimes the video inexplicably starts playing very fast, as if in fast forward. I've also had similar issues when streaming just audio, not video. When I stream a song, for example, it might also skip and/or go into fast forward mode. Couldn't find an answer to this anywhere. Any thoughts? Please help!

Linux Mint 13 Maya 64 bit
Intel 2500K (using on-board graphics, no separate video card)
Asus p8 z68 vlx mobo

Comment: If this issue appears with flash only, try the solution I outlined in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187864/is-there-any-way-to-synchronize-flash-audio-and-video/187870#187870

Comment: I don't think it's flash only because it can happen if I stream just an audio file -- wouldn't that rule out flash?

Comment: It depends on how you stream the audio file. Soundcloud, for instance, uses a flash player.

Comment: I see. there were two shockwave flash listed and I disabled one. I guess I'll have to see if that works since the problem is sporadic. thanks for the tip

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: so, unfortunately that did not solve the problem. still skipping, etc.

Comment: I answered a question similar to this. Here was my response. http://askubuntu.com/questions/176882/flash-video-problem-ubuntu-12-04/176883#176883 . Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? I had a similar problem a couple of weeks back and the problem was actually Chrome. Try turning off flash in your plugins so that Chrome defaults to using the flash on your computer. That fixed it for me.